# pysmb - reads a file while the file is written by another system

Tags: python-3.x, pysmb

I have a scenario where few external programs/system writes file to shared drive. sometimes users may also copy files to the shared drive.

I have developed a simple python program to read the files continuously from the same shared drive and perform few operations on it. Basically this program polls the folder and remove the file from shared drive once the operation is completed

I'm first using `conn.listPath` to get all the files and using `conn.retrieveFile` to retrieve files one by one. Now we observe that certain big files takes a while for external system to copy to shared drive. However it looks like pysmb attempts to retrieves the file even when the copy is only half a way through. this causes some exception.

while the exceptions are handled now, I would like to know if there is a way to list/retrieve a file only when it is fully copied.

Many Thanks.